# Since establishes an alias of the following command?

Tags: bash, git, github, git-bash

Hello I am trying to establish in the following **alias** with `gitbash` and cannot :

```
alias dirpwd='$(`pwd | xargs dirname | xargs basename -a`)' && echo -e $dirpwd;
```

The output is :

```
bash: c: command not found
```

Why?

Thanks all !!

Comment: I suggest to use a function. See: `help function`

Comment: What about the `echo` part? Is `$dirpwd` an actual variable you want to print in addition to the pwd part? Please give an example like »I'm in `/this/is/my/dir`. The `dirpwd` should print `my`«.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What happens:**

Backticks and `$()` work in the same way. The command inside them gets executed and the resulting output is treated as if you typed it in directly.

Assume you are in `/top/c/bottom`.
The part `pwd | xargs dirname | xargs basename -a` inside the backticks has output `c`.
Bash replaces the backtick part with its output, resulting in the command `$(c)`.
Now bash tries to execute the command inside `$(...)` but `c` is not a command, hence the error `bash: c: command not found`.

**First Fix:**

I guess you just want to write

```
alias dirpwd="pwd | xargs dirname | xargs basename -a"
```

**Bug:**

There is a hidden bug. `xargs` splits at spaces and may pass multiple arguments to `dirname` and `basename`.

Example:   Assume you you are in `/top/a b c/`. `xarg` creates the following command and output

```
dirname "/top/a" "b" "c/"
```

```
/top
.
.
```

**Second Fix:**

Use `$()` instead of `xargs`.

```
alias dirpwd='basename "$(dirname "$PWD")"'
```

Comment: And `alias dirpwd='dirpwd=$(basename "$(dirname "$(pwd)")"); echo "$dirpwd"'` sets an alias `dirpwd` which both sets the variable `$dirpwd` and echoes the value in it.  That works with perverse names with double spaces at the start and end and in the middle of multiple levels of directory name.

Answer (score 0):

Try how an solution is :

```
alias dirpwd="pwd | xargs dirname | xargs basename -a"
```